# Setting Width & Height of ListView inside TabPage

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, tabcontrol, tabpage

I am trying to set the Width & Height of a `ListView` inside a `TabPage` on the Window resize event, i had some success being able to set the values correctly though while switching to another tab i notice that the size was only set correctly on the tab which was selected while the window was resized.

Is it possible to set the width of a `ListView` in a `TabPage` even though it isn't selected?

The code which is run on resize:

```
foreach (TabPage tab in TabControl.TabPages)
{
    foreach (Control c in tab.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Forms.ListView")
        {
            c.Width = tab.Width;
            c.Height = tab.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Has the `ListView` been displayed yet?  If not, it hasn't yet been through its layout sequence.  Meaning that nothing you do will stick until it has been shown.  Perhaps keep the size(s) in memory and apply them at `TabControl::SelectedIndexChanged()`.

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? Set the `Anchor` or `Dock`. It will take care of the `ListView` size when resized.